# How to affect an element when overlapping?

Tags: html, css

I have the following code
How can I affect the properties of the circle when it overlaps with the square?
While it overlaps with the square, I want to be able to affect its opacity, color, size, for example before it overlaps with the square to have a green color and a certain size, and when it overlaps with the square I would like it to have a different size and another color.

I thought about animation, that is, the circle should be green for a few seconds and a few seconds for another color, but it's a very imprecise method and I don't think it's good.
What other solutions are there?

But what if I wanted to affect the background color by targeting my body?
Is it possible that when the circle crosses the square I have a different background color?

```css
body {
  background: grey;
}

.box2 {
  background: blue;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  position: relative;
  left: 200px;
  top: 100px;
}

.box3 {
  background: green;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  left: 200px;
  top: 200px;
  animation: circle 10s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes circle {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(0)
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(650px);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="box1"> </div>
<div class="box2"> </div>
<div class="box3"> </div>
```

Comment: the CSS language offers calculation functions. remains to be calculated in advance according to the forms those of the time and the distance to change your color. Otherwise you must establish your geometric calculations and speeds in javascript